# crammed data received,where is the end of data?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I have **chatting application**, with **multiple clients** and **one server**.
I want to receive separated and full data, and the data can be text(string) or file (bytes).
for example.
client1 send data1(text) and data2(image). as the same time.
the server receive the two messages as a single message (data1data2).

***how can i know where the data1 ends?***

my solution i have tried but not working, is:
adding "END_OF_PACKET" string which converted to byte[] when client is sending data.
sometimes it works when i treat data as byte[]. failing on string.

**What the methods can i use to make this work?**

Comment: Why not just put the block lengths at the start of the message? Assuming you use the `BitConverter` you can encode the lengths using a known number of bytes, thus being able to read them reliably and giving you proper indexing into the stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> sometimes it works when i treat data as byte[]. failing on string.

It's because a byte[] has a fixed encoding, it's a raw version of your string, so if you encode (string -> byte[]) your message in a certain charset (let's say UTF-8) you have to decode (byte[] -> string) with the same charset (UFT-8) to retrieve the original message.

---

> how can i know where the data1 ends?

Since you also want to pass binary datas, you shouldn't use the "END_OF_PACKET" solution.
Why? Because inside your binary datas there could be one (or more) match of this string, consider binary datas as unpredictable and using all possible characters.

So here is another solution:
Start your message with a number which will represent the message length + a separator (other than a digit) to know where the number ends, then add your data (binary or not).

Syntax: `<length><separator><data>`
With separator=";" :
`4;Hello19;Look at this image!20;jœÿJ¯ÿTÀÿRŒ»ÿP‰»ÿ=kF`

There are 3 data in the previous example:
 1. `4;Hello`
 2. `19;Look at this image!`
 3. `20;jœÿJ¯ÿTÀÿRŒ»ÿP‰»ÿ=kF`